Expectation of a product of CDFs
I frequently encounter equations of the type
$\log \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \prod_{i=1}^N\Phi(a_i x+b_i)~\mathrm{d}x$
where $\phi$ is a pdf (often Gaussian, Gumbel, Logistic) and $\Phi$ is a cdf (same distribution as pdf). Sometimes even
$\log \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \prod_{i=1}^N\Phi(a_i x+b_i)\prod_{j=N+1}^{2N}(1-\Phi(a_j x+b_j))~\mathrm{d}x$
Is there any known techniques to solve this type of equation? Even a starting point or reference would help after six months of banging my head on the table...

Integrals of the form $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) \prod_{i=1}^N\Phi(a_i x+b_i)\,\mathrm{d}x$ can be interpreted as asking for the probability that a random variable $X_0$ with CDF $\Phi(x)$ and pdf $\phi(x)$ is larger than the maximum of $N$ independent random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_N$ with respective CDFs $\Phi(a_ix_i + b_i)$ and pdfs $a_i\phi(a_ix_i + b_i)$, $i = 1,2,\ldots, N$. Note that the $X_i, i = 0,1,\ldots, N$ are $N+1$ mutually independent random variables. For the special case of $X_0 \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ ($\mu > 0$) and the other $X_i \sim \mathcal N(\sigma^2)$, this calculation (actually the calculation of the complementary probability) has been studied extensively by communications engineers under the name $M$-ary orthogonal signaling. See, for example, this answer of mine over on stats.SE.
Unfortunately, no closed-form solutions are known even for this special case, and numerical integration is necessary.

The first equation becomes a multivariate CDF for normal distributions where $x$ will be marginalized out.
For $a_i = a$  being the same for all $i$, the Gumbel also has an analytical solution.
These are the only cases where I would see solutions...
